# How to generate UK bank account number

Tags: algorithm

Is there an algorithm for generating UK bank account numbers.
There is an algorithm for validation (called "Modulus checking" by Vocalink), but not for generating.
The bank will give me the sort code, so I just need to generate the account number. 
If there is no generation algorithm, why is that ?

Comment: why u generate uk bank account number... have u any authority to create account?

Comment: I generate virtual IBANs. The account number is part of the IBAN structure.

Comment: want to generate by using which language?

Comment: The language doesn't matter, I need the algorithm.

Answer (score 0):

UK bank account numbers contains a six-digit sort code that identifies the branch of the bank where the account is held. Typically the first two digits identify the bank itself and the remaining four digits the specific branch in the bank.

These numbers are not algorithmic, they are simply just a list. Therefore there is no way of generating bank account numbers algorithmically especially without knowing where the account is held, i.e. the bank and the branch in the bank.

I think you can buy lists from banks containing information of different sort code identification but they are expensive. You can see some common sort codes in [this article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sort_code#List_of_sort_codes_of_the_United_Kingdom).

Comment: The bank will give me the sort code. I just need to generate the account number.